# Flutter custom sound local notification not working

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, flutter-local-notification

I want to change the notification sound with the local notification package in flutter, it works fine on the android side but there is a problem on the iOS side

no problem when i send this body to this link https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with postman i can hear the notification sound I want

```
{
    "to" : "My device Id",
    "notification" : {
        "title" : "Sound test",
        "body" : "Sound body",
        "sound" : "sound.wav"
    }
}
```

but when I want to get this sound in all notifications, the notification comes but I don't hear any sound.
This is my complete code

```
class NotificationServices {
  CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = CustomerViewModel();
  //initialising firebase message plugin
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  //initialising firebase message plugin
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  //function to initialise flutter local notification plugin to show notifications for android when app is active
  void initLocalNotifications(
      BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidInitializationSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
    var iosInitializationSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );

    var initializationSetting = InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings, iOS: iosInitializationSettings);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSetting,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
      // handle interaction when app is active for android
      handleMessage(context, message);
    });
  }

  void firebaseInit(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;

      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("notifications title:${notification!.title}");
        print("notifications body:${notification.body}");
        print('count:${android!.count}');
        print('data:${message.data.toString()}');
      }

      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        forgroundMessage();
      }

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        initLocalNotifications(context, message);
        showNotification(message);
      }
    });
  }

  void requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: true,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('user granted permission');
      }
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('user granted provisional permission');
      }
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('user denied permission');
      }
    }
  }

  // function to show visible notification when app is active
  Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
        message.notification!.android!.channelId.toString(),
        message.notification!.android!.channelId.toString(),
        importance: Importance.max,
        showBadge: true,
        playSound: true,
        sound: const RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'));

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'bana_lazimsin_channel', 'High Importance Notifications',
            channelDescription:
                'This channel is used for important notifications',
            importance: Importance.high,
            priority: Priority.high,
            playSound: true,
            ticker: 'ticker',
            icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 15, 123),
            sound: channel.sound);
    DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        const DarwinNotificationDetails(sound: 'notification.wav'
            // presentAlert: true,
            // presentBadge: true,
            // presentSound: true,
            );

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        message.notification!.title.toString(),
        message.notification!.body.toString(),
        notificationDetails,
      );
    });
  }

  //function to get device token on which we will send the notifications
  Future<String> getDeviceToken() async {
    String? token = await messaging.getToken();
    return token!;
  }

  void isTokenRefresh() async {
    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
      event.toString();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('refresh');
      }
    });
  }

  //handle tap on notification when app is in background or terminated
  Future<void> setupInteractMessage(BuildContext context) async {
    // when app is terminated
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
      handleMessage(context, initialMessage);
    }

    //when app ins background
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      handleMessage(context, event);
    });
  }

  void handleMessage(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'message') {
      String customerId = message.data['customerId'];
      Customer? customer =
          await customerViewModel.fetchOtherCustomer(customerId);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ChatPage(customer: customer!)));
    } else if (message.data['type'] == 'Job') {
      String jobId = message.data['itemId'];
      int parsedJobId = int.parse(jobId);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => UserJobDetailPage(
                    jobId: parsedJobId,
                  )));
    } else if (message.data['type'] == 'JobOffer') {
      String jobId = message.data['itemId'];
      int parsedJobId = int.parse(jobId);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => JobOfferDetailPage(
                    jobId: parsedJobId,
                    isActive: true,
                  )));
    } else if (message.data['type'] == 'NewJob') {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const MainPage(
              isBidder: true,
            ),
          ));
    } else {}
  }

  Future forgroundMessage() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }
}
```

```
If (Platform.isIOS) { in firebaseInit function
        forgroundMessage();
      }
```

part I think it only runs the forgroundMessage part without running other functions related to iOS and finishes

and my main.dart file

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and the part where I call them in initState on the main_page of my application

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    loginViewModel = Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    notificationServices.requestNotificationPermission();
    notificationServices.forgroundMessage();
    notificationServices.firebaseInit(context);
    notificationServices.setupInteractMessage(context);
    notificationServices.isTokenRefresh();

    notificationServices.getDeviceToken().then((value) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('device token');
        print(value);
      }
    });
    upBody = widget.isBidder ? const HomePageForBidder() : const HomePage();

    for (var tab in tabIconsList) {
      tab.isSelected = false;
    }
    tabIconsList[0].isSelected = true;

    animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600), vsync: this);

    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let make sure you saved notification.wav in the root folder of Runner.xcworkspace